# How to make Python get_wch capture Enter key?

Tags: python, ncurses, python-3.3

When I am using

```
ch = wnd.getch()
```

in `curses` under Python, I can capture the enter key which `wnd.getch` returns 10. However it does not work when I replaced `getch` by `get_wch`. Is there any problems with `get_wch`?

Comment: PS: TAB key is also one of the problem. `getch` returns 9 but `get_wch` does not work either.

Comment: Works for me. It returns '\n' for enter and '\t' for tab.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `getch` and `get_wch` have different interfaces:

- `getch` returns a *character*
- `get_wch` returns a *status code*, and *sets* a wide character via the pointer passed as a parameter.

They use different interfaces because special keys (such as `KEY_HOME`) can be handled with `getch` as "extra" characters beyond the range of "normal" (8-bit) characters.  You cannot do that with wide characters (not as easily, since the end of the wide character range is less definite), so `get_wch` uses a status code to tell if the value that it sets via the pointer is a wide character or a special key.

Although the *manual page* is clear enough, the python developers did not notice this distinction when adding the feature to the curses wrapper.  The *description* in the Python documentation corresponds to `getch` rather than `get_wch`:

- [Issues #15785: curses.get_wch() returns keypad codes incorrectly](https://bugs.python.org/issue15785)

  The bug report indicates that a fix was applied to python **3.4**.
- [16.10. curses — Terminal handling for character-cell displays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html)
- [`window.get_wch([y, x])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.get_wch)

> Get a wide character. Return a character for most keys, or an integer for function keys, keypad keys, and other special keys.
>
> *New in version 3.3.*

Further reading:

- [**`getch`**, `wgetch`, **`mvgetch`**, **`mvwgetch`**, **`ungetch`**, **`has_key`** - get (or push back) characters from curses terminal keyboard](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html)
- [**`get_wch`**, **`wget_wch`**, **`mvget_wch`**, **`mvwget_wch`**, **`unget_wch`** - get (or push back) a wide character from curses terminal
     keyboard](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html)